# Como transformar a cada dois registros de um DatFrame em um só no Python com base em duas colunas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho um DataFrame em que a cada duas linhas referem-se a um registro apenas. Preciso fazer uma união dessas linhas com base no "id" e no "mandante" para transformar em uma só. A coluna "mandante" tem valor 1 indicando que o time é o mandante.

```
lst = [["1001","1","LA Lakers", 105, 12],["1001","0","Utah Jazz", 99, 10], ["1002","1","Chicago Bulls", 95, 8], ["1002","0","Orlando Magic", 90, 9], ["1003","1","Denver Nuggets", 101, 17], ["1003","0","Miami Heat", 84, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ["id", "mandante", "time", "pontuacao", "faltas"])

   id    mandante  time            pontuacao  faltas
0  1001  1         LA Lakers       105        12   
1  1001  0         Utah Jazz       99         10
2  1002  1         Chicago Bulls   95         8   
3  1002  0         Orlando Magic   90         9
4  1003  1         Denver Nuggets  101        17   
5  1004  0         Miami Heat      84         6
```

Preciso que o DataFrame fique da seguinte forma:

```
   id    mandante       visitante       pts_mandante  pts_visitante  flts_mandante  flts_visitante
0  1001  LA Lakers      Utah Jazz       105           99             12               10
2  1002  Chicago Bulls  Orlando Magic   95            90             8                9   
4  1003  Denver Nuggets Miami Heat      101           84             17               6
```

Não tem problema se ficar com a coluna repetida, depois eu excluo com facilidade. O principal é conseguir jogar todas as informações de mesmo "id" em um registro index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma seria dividir o DF em 2, entre mandantes e visitantes, renomear as colunas de cada DF de acordo como você deseja e com `merge` uni-los novamente, desta forma:

```
mask = df['mandante'] == '1'

df = df.drop(columns = ['mandante'])

mandante = df.loc[mask]
visitante = df.loc[~mask]

colunas_mandante = ['id', 'mandante', 'pts_mandante',  'flts_mandante']
colunas_visitante = ['id', 'visitante', 'pts_visitante',  'flts_visitante']


mandante.columns = colunas_mandante
visitante.columns = colunas_visitante

df_new = mandante.merge(visitante, on='id')

#saida:

    id          mandante        pts_mandante    flts_mandante   visitante       pts_visitante   flts_visitante
0   1001        LA Lakers       105             12              Utah Jazz       99              10
1   1002        Chicago Bulls   95              8               Orlando Magic   90              9
2   1003        Denver Nuggets  101             17              Miami Heat      84              6
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma bem simples de obter esse resultado é utilizando o método [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) do pandas.

Basicamente ele remodela o **dataframe** a partir de valores de indice e colunas fornecidos por você.

Exemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd

lst = [
   ["1001","1","LA Lakers", 105, 12],
   ["1001","0","Utah Jazz", 99, 10],
   ["1002","1","Chicago Bulls", 95, 8],
   ["1002","0","Orlando Magic", 90, 9],
   ["1003","1","Denver Nuggets", 101, 17],
   ["1003","0","Miami Heat", 84, 6]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ["id", "mandante", "time", "pontuacao", "faltas"])

print(df)

# Output:
#      id mandante            time  pontuacao  faltas
# 0  1001        1       LA Lakers        105      12
# 1  1001        0       Utah Jazz         99      10
# 2  1002        1   Chicago Bulls         95       8
# 3  1002        0   Orlando Magic         90       9
# 4  1003        1  Denver Nuggets        101      17
# 5  1003        0      Miami Heat         84       6
```

Utilizando o método *pivot*, selecione duas colunas. A primeira será utilizada como indice e a segunda é utilizada para "dividir" os valores das outras colunas, como se fosse um segundo nivel de coluna.

```py
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='id', columns='mandante')

print(df_pivot)

# Output:
#                    time                 pontuacao      faltas    
# mandante              0               1         0    1      0   1
# id                                                               
# 1001          Utah Jazz       LA Lakers        99  105     10  12
# 1002      Orlando Magic   Chicago Bulls        90   95      9   8
# 1003         Miami Heat  Denver Nuggets        84  101      6  17
```

Para deixar o **dataframe** como o esperado, basta renomear as colunas.

```py
colunas = [
   'visitante', 'mandante', 'pts_visitante',
   'pts_mandante', 'flts_visitante', 'flts_mandante'
]

# Renomeando o nome das colunas no Dataframe
df_pivot.columns = colunas

# Resetando os indices criados na etapa de pivotagem.
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()

print(df_pivot)

# Output:
#      id      visitante        mandante  pts_visitante  pts_mandante  flts_visitante  flts_mandante
# 0  1001      Utah Jazz       LA Lakers             99           105              10             12
# 1  1002  Orlando Magic   Chicago Bulls             90            95               9              8
# 2  1003     Miami Heat  Denver Nuggets             84           101               6             17
```

**Referências**:

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot